# Configure a task to repeat on every change to upstream tasks

Tags: dependencies, airflow, task, repeat, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am designing a DAG which processes several data sources and outputs a report. The DAG, as a whole, is triggered daily. Schematically:

```
src1 --┐
src2 --┤
...  --┼---> report
srcN --┘
```

By default, a task waits for all upstream tasks to finish successfully. In my case, the source tasks are triggered at different times and have non-uniform runtimes. Yet, I would like to have a report, outside Airflow, that reflects the up-to-date state of the system. For this reason, I want to trigger the `report` task multiple time - initially when the DAG is initialized (to create a placeholder report), and later whenever each of the `src` tasks is done.

For the purposes of the question, assume all the `report` task does is pull the status of all upstream tasks and store them in a file, in the form of `src1: {N/A, success, failure}` entries.

To achieve this outside of Airflow, I'd likely set up a pub-sub channel between the source tasks and the `report` and have each task notify when it's done (regardless of outcome), and the reporting service, which is subscribed to these notifications, will run whenever notified.

One solution I had in mind was to create a periodically running task, in a separate DAG, that looks for some output files generated by each of the `src` tasks individually, assigning N/A when the files are missing. Thus, a UX similar to an auto-updating report is achieved. Then, the `report` task is effectively disconnected from this DAG and it becomes a collection of unconnected task{group}s.

Several questions:

1. Is the workflow I have in mind suitable for Airflow?
2. Assuming this is doable, how should I configure the DAG itself and/or the `report` task to achieve what I want? I considered the various [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#trigger-rules) for `report`, but these seem to only trigger `report` once.
3. To create a placeholder report, I thought to create a dummy task which finishes immediately and causes `report` to run using whichever mechanism, and `report` would ignore the dummy task in the report. Is there a more straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using a separated DAG to do the report, and trigger a run for that DAG each time a source is finished using a [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html) to refresh your data ?

Comment: @vdolez Thanks for the tip! I have not considered that operator (I'm new to Airflow and unfamiliar with all of its capabilities). If possible, please add that as an answer including instructions on how to configure the secondary dag to run on its own as well as on-trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use at least 2 DAGs:

- a DAG to handle all sources
- a DAG to handle your Report

Some code sample would look like this:

```py
with DAG(dag_id="producer", ...):
    for src in [src1, src2, src3]:
        producer = BashOperator(task_id="producer_"+src.name, ...)
        refresh = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id="refresh_from_"+src.name,
            trigger_dag_id="consumer",
            trigger_run_id="",
            reset_dag_run=True,
             ...)
        producer >> refresh

with DAG(dag_id="consumer", ...):
    BashOperator(task_id="build_or_refresh_report", ...)
    ...
```

As a good practice you should provide the appropriate **trigger_run_id** TriggerDagRunOperator in order to reuse the same DAG_run object, otherwise you could trigger a "manual" dag_run.

It would respect idem-potency principles and would lower the amount of DAG runs stored in Database. In general, DAGs should have a define schedule to operate a specific period of time.

If you use the same **trigger_run_id** and want your Report to be executed multiple times you must use **reset_dag_run=True**.

It would be easier to guess the trigger_run id if your Source DAG(s) use the same schedule as the Report DAG but it's not mandatory.

As stated by [RNHTTR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77729371/2508468) the normal way to achieve your goal should be [the Dataset feature](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html) but it's a relatively recent thing and possibilities are limited at the moment.

Useful sources:

- [Astronomer: Cross-DAG dependencies: triggerdagrunoperator](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/cross-dag-dependencies?tab=traditional#triggerdagrunoperator)
- [Airflow Documentation: TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator)
- [Airflow: Core Concepts: DAG Runs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html)
- [Astronomer: DAG writing best practices](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dag-best-practices)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Per recommendation of [RNHTTR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77729371/3372061), I suggest adding a `trigger_rule=all_done` to `refresh` to better align with the question's requirements. Another useful resource is [astronomer: datasets](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-datasets), especially in its reference to [listeners](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/listeners.html#listeners), which are another potential tool to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the good practice you mentioned (doc link would be fine). Why don't I want multiple DagRuns? Is it a question of resource utilization? Is it related to the ability to abort "outdated" runs? Should I use the same run id for all reporting tasks or for all tasks across all DAGs in my project?

Comment: @Dev-iL I added some explanations about why reusing the `trigger_run_id` would be best. I recommend you to read [Astronomer's Best Practices](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dag-best-practices) to understand why idempotency is a cool feature, especially when you want to retry failed DAGs. Also, why would you want to refresh your Report if the source failed ?

Comment: a failure is a very important piece of feedback, since it means there's something wrong with the data source (e.g. the source data changed/damaged/missing, SLA violation). I suppose it's possible to set it up in such a way that a "failed processing" ≠ "failed task" (i.e. the data/processing issue is reported where needed and the task is marked as done), yet the current problem definition makes more sense to me since it "invites" the user to restart the task once the issue has been removed. I think the task shouldn't rerun w/o user intervention unless it was some internal error.

Comment: @Dev-iL a failure is important feedback, that's why you can natively use email alerting and that's why you can use [callback functions](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html). Knowing the Business State of a task is also very useful and using idempotency within Airflow reflects this perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a straightforward way to do this today, but there's an [open feature request](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/34534). It'd be great if you wanted to work on it!

Like @vdolez mentioned, you could separate `report` into its own DAG, then have a TriggerDagRunOperator downstream of all `srcN` tasks with a [trigger rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/concepts.html#trigger-rules) of `none_failed`.

Comment: Thanks for the issue link! Digging through the related threads, I came upon [this workaround](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28333#issuecomment-1357534240), which could be relevant.

Comment: Well, actually, if all producers output the same dataset, the consumer would be refreshed each time.